# Passing json to request body using restkit in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I am using restkit in my application to post /get anything from my webservice.
I am having a nested json which i want to post to the request body of my API. I have used the following code to pass json to the request body of my service but when I run application it returns null in my request body.

This is my nested json which I want to pass to the request body

```
{
    amount =     {
        currency = INR;
        value = 1;
    };
    merchantAccessKey = UDNIRNIRFBNRIRN;
    merchantTxnId = sssscdcdcdEDFF;
    notifyUrl = "";
    paymentToken =     {
        paymentMode =         {
            cvv = 968;
            expiry = “11/20”;
            holder = AXIS;
            number = xxxxxxxxxxxx;
            scheme = asxsc;
            type = debit;
        };
        type = paymentOptionToken;
    };
    requestSignature = abgd9456fef7b3f9023232734706;
    returnUrl = "https://www.example.com/";
    userDetails =     {
        address =         {
            city = "";
            country = "";
            state = "";
            street1 = "";
            street2 = "";
            zip = "";
        };
        email = “abc@gmail.com”;
        firstName = abc;
        lastName = xyz;
        mobileNo = 1234567890;
    };
}
```

This is my code for sending the json to API.

```
- (void)ComplexRequestMapping{
 RKObjectMapping* paymentamount = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];

  RKObjectMapping* amountMapping =
      [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Amount class]];
  [amountMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
                     @{@"currency" : @"currency", @"value" : @"value"}];
  [paymentamount
      addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
                             relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"amount"
                                                  toKeyPath:@"amount"
                                                withMapping:amountMapping]];

  RKObjectMapping* userdetailsMapping =
      [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserDetails class]];
  [userdetailsMapping
      addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                           @"email" : @"email",
                                           @"firstName" : @"firstName",
                                           @"lastName" : @"lastName",
                                           @"mobileNo" : @"mobileNo"
                                         }];
  RKObjectMapping* addressMapping =
      [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UserAddress class]];
  [addressMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"city" : @"city",
                                                       @"country" : @"country",
                                                       @"state" : @"state",
                                                       @"street1" : @"street1",
                                                       @"street2" : @"street2",
                                                       @"zip" : @"zip"
                                                     }];
  [addressMapping
      addPropertyMapping:
          [RKRelationshipMapping
              relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"address"
                                   toKeyPath:@"address"
                                 withMapping:[userdetailsMapping
                                                     inverseMapping]]];

  RKObjectMapping* paymentTokenMapping =
      [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CTSPaymentToken class]];
  [paymentTokenMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"type" : @"type"}];

  RKObjectMapping* paymentOptionsMapping =
      [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CTSPaymentOption class]];
  [paymentOptionsMapping
      addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                           @"cvv" : @"cvv",
                                           @"expiry" : @"expiry",
                                           @"holder" : @"holder",
                                           @"number" : @"number",
                                           @"scheme" : @"scheme",
                                           @"type" : @"type"
                                         }];
  [paymentOptionsMapping
      addPropertyMapping:
          [RKRelationshipMapping
              relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"paymentMode"
                                   toKeyPath:@"paymentMode"
                                 withMapping:[paymentTokenMapping
                                                     inverseMapping]]];
  RKRequestDescriptor* requestDes = [RKRequestDescriptor
      requestDescriptorWithMapping:amountMapping
                       objectClass:[CTSPaymentRequest class]
                       rootKeyPath:nil
                            method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
  [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDes];

}
```

Comment: Just try with simple json data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with simple json 
{
   title = Test;
   body = Sample text;
   auther = Test author;
}
// by using NSJson class you can convert json data to object.Here i manually create my own object

    yourObject *object = [yourObject new];
    object.title = @“Test”;
    object.body = @“Sample text”;
    object.author = @“Test auther”;

    RKResponseDescriptor * yourObjectDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/test" keyPath:@"test" statusCodes:statusCodes];
    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"title", @"author", @"body"]];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[yourObject class] rootKeyPath:@“test” method:RKRequestMethodAny];

    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:BASE_URL];
    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

    // POST to create
    [manager postObject:object path:@“/test” parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what is wrong, but I guess you get a crash when you try to send complaining about the request mappings...

When creating request mappings the destination class has to be a mutable dictionary. This is what `requestMapping` and `inverseMapping` create for you.

At the moment you seem to randomly combine response and request style mappings where you need to be consistent. Either create a response mapping and then take the inverse to create the request mapping or create and associate multiple request mapping parts.